# Qt css background translucent

Tags: css, qt, qt-designer

How do I set the background of a `QFrame` to translucent so that I can kinda see through to the background of the parent widget (`QWidget`). I tried this but the background remains black:

```
QFrame {    
    margin: 10px;
    background: #000000;
    border: 1px solid black;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: Did you try adding `setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);`

Comment: How do you do that when using QT designer?

Comment: Do this in your constructor

Comment: I've just tried it. It makes it completely transparent

Comment: Call setWindowOpacity(0.5)?

Comment: That doesn't work either

Comment: Well I can help you more right now, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this...

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

    setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_PaintOnScreen);

    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents);
}

void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
    QPainter p(this);
    QString text = "Some foo goes here";
    QFontMetrics metrics(p.font());
    resize(metrics.size(0, text));
    p.drawText(rect(), Qt::AlignCenter, text);
}
```

Comment: It needs to be translucent